# How to increase digitcount in Digital Gauge?

Tags: jscript, gauge, dundas

I'm trying to use application that was developed using .NET.

- This application uses Dundas Gauges (third party included in my application).
- Application uses jscript.net. I'm trying to use Digital gauge.

**The problem that I have:**

The number count is limited to 5. In my case I have 6 digits to display. If I provide 5 digits it works, if I provide 6 digits .. instead of displaying those numbers I see 'ERROR'

**My question:**

How could I increase allowed digit count? I used this code:

```
var digitGauge : GaugeControl = GaugeControl( form.All( "digitGauge" ) );
digitGauge.Value = 123456;
```

Note: I was looking for property DigitCount for variable digitGauge .. but it does not exist.
Could someone help me and correct my code?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am taking off this question. I decided not to use this type of gauge